# Log warning about required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop

Tags: gnome

I have a brand new laptop and running Ubuntu 18.10 on Wayland. Everything is working fine but I am keeping an eye on the logs. Today a new warning appeared:

```
Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
```

What does this mean? There doesn't seem to be any problems at all with the laptop or with Gnome.

EDIT. Output of ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions requested below:

```
N8xxEZ:~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
insgesamt 72
drwxrwxr-x 18  4096 Mär 21 08:51 .
drwx------  3  4096 Mär 21 18:21 ..
drwxrwxr-x  4  4096 Mär 21 08:51 activities-config@nls1729
drwxrwxr-x  7  4096 Mär 17 15:38 apt-update-indicator@franglais125.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  5  4096 Mär 17 15:39 caffeine@patapon.info
drwxrwxr-x  4  4096 Mär 15 10:39 clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com
drwxrwxr-x  5  4096 Mär 15 10:39 dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  3  4096 Mär 20 13:51 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  6  4096 Mär 15 10:41 freon@UshakovVasilii_Github.yahoo.com
drwxrwxr-x  5  4096 Mär 20 13:41 gnome-shell-screenshot@ttll.de
drwxrwxr-x  5  4096 Mär 15 10:44 IP-Finder@linxgem33.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  3  4096 Mär 15 20:00 night-light-slider.timur@linux.com
drwxrwxr-x  4  4096 Mär 16 03:20 openweather-extension@jenslody.de
drwxrwxr-x  3  4096 Mär 17 15:38 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  2  4096 Mär 17 15:53 remove-dropdown-arrows@mpdeimos.com
drwxrwxr-x  2  4096 Mär 15 20:07 synaptic-button@fthx
drwxrwxr-x  5  4096 Mär 21 20:13 touchpad-indicator@orangeshirt
drwxr-xr-x  3  4096 Mär 15 11:48 xorwayland@fepede.net
N8xxEZ:~$
```

Comment: Wayland is probably the problem. At your login screen, click the cogwheel icon and choose "Ubuntu". Also, you could have a bad GNOME extension. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema But I want to use Wayland rather than Xorg!

Comment: Well, then you're probably going to have problems. Wayland is not really ready for prime time. Try my suggestion, and see if it helps. You can always go back. Report back.

Comment: I've been using Wayland since Ubuntu 17.10, so for almost 18 months on my old laptop without any problems. But anyway, I booted into Xorg and the same warning appears. So it is not Wayland that is causing the warning. By the way, there is no problem or symptoms, other than the warning, in either Xorg or Wayland.

Comment: Fair enough. Edit your question with the output of `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Ok done that. I think you might be on to something. I have been adding Gnome extensions recently.

Comment: Disable ALL extensions and see if the problem goes away. If it does, one of them is causing the problem. Re-enable some, recheck the log, etc. I think that dash-to-dock, freon, openweather, and touchpad-indicator are probably ok. Another way to find bad ones is look in /var/log/syslog for "gnome-shell", as that's were those get logged. Report back.

Comment: Hi, still have the same problem but I have narrowed it down to this line in my syslog file: "failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_AU_Optronics_gdm_123"

Comment: Did you disable all extensions to see if the problem went away?

Comment: Not yet, that is my last resort as the errors do not always appear at startup and so this would take a lot of time which I don't have. As I said the problem is not causing any problems except for the error message. The message from the syslog is sent from "gsd.color" by the way.